# What are the most important differences between full AppServer (like JBossAS) and Seam?

Tags: jboss, seam

If client of the system is on the web there are no advantages JBossAS+Seam over Tomcat+Seam?

Answer (score 6):

Your questions suggests you're confused about what is what.

Seam is a framework for building web applications in Java.

JBoss AS is a Java EE application server.

Tomcat is a Java servlet container.

You can run Seam on either JBoss or Tomcat.

Since JBoss is a full EE app. server, you get certain features like Enterprise Java Beans out of the box with JBoss.

With Tomcat, you don't, but this isn't usually a big concern since, for example, [Spring framework](http://www.springsource.org/) can replace Java EE if you need that functionality.

It does matter what you use, since the majority of your system will be probably coded in the back end (server side Java).

If you want the minimum amount of hassle when using Seam, I'd suggest using JBoss since that company made Seam.

Comment: Seam with Tomcat doesn't support EJB?

Comment: @inv: Tomcat has no built in EJB support.

Comment: @darioo But Seam is integration JSF with EJB, right? And it can work in Tomcat.

Comment: @inv: true; but you need to install [embedded JBoss on Tomcat](http://docs.jboss.com/seam/latest/reference/en-US/html/configuration.html#config.install.embedded) for Seam to work correctly. That's why I recommended that you use JBoss AS if you want to use Seam.

Comment: Seam integrates an embedded Jboss to provide EJBs in tomcat.